# How to use DotNetZip Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetzip

I unziped the file I donwloaded. how and what library do i access in my asp.net mvc 3 app to be able to unzip a file that contains multiple files?

my controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Upload(ScormUploadViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (model.ScormPackageFile != null)
    {
      string zipCurFile = model.ScormPackageFile.FileName;
      string fullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(zipCurFile);
      string directoryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipCurFile);
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(fullPath, directoryName));

      using (FileStream zipFile = new FileStream(zipCurFile, FileMode.Open))
      {
        using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(zipFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zipStream);  
         //next unzip the file? how to get the library i need?
        }
      }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you read through their [example code](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)?

Comment: i see alot of examples that i will look at later,but for now I need to set it up so I can access it in VS?

Comment: Sure, but in order to set it up in VS, you will need to write some code. That's why the library has documentation and examples. So that you read them and write the required code.